# Usage of そして、ごかぞく、ときどき and some questions on forming sentence

Tags: translation

I'm trying to write a simple Japanese composition using phrases I have learnt (yes, it's homework). I encountered a number of questions.

Below I have listed what I intend to say in English, and my translation. I have bolded the parts which I am unsure of whether the usage is correct.

1. His birthday is on 28 January **and** he is 25 years old this year. 

   たんじょうびはいちがつにじうはちにちです。**そしてことし**にじうごさいです。

   >>*Is my usage of そして to join the sentence correct here? Also, is ことし necessary?*
2. He has 4 members in his family.

   Peter-さんの**ごかぞく**はよにんです。

   >>*Should I be using ごかぞく or just かぞく here?*
3. Every Friday after class, **we** go out to eat lunch. **He is very stingy, so we always go to cheap restaurants.**

   *まいきんようび**いっしょに**レストランでひるごはんをたへます。**かれはとてもけちですから、いつもやすいのレストランへいきます。***

   >>*Should I use 私たしたち or いっしょに? For the second bolded part, I'm not even sure if it makes sense in japanese.*
4. I like to eat spicy food, **but he does not.**

   わたしはからいたべものがだいすきです**が、かれはからいたべものがすきじゃありません**。

   >>*Is this correct? It does not seem too elegant if you ask me.*
5. **After, we sometimes** watch movies at cinemas. 

   **それから、ときと**えいがかんでえいがをみます。

   >>*Is my usage of ときどきhere correct?*
6. We like action movies **because we lack action in our life.**

   **わたしたちのせいかつはあまりおもしろいくないですから**、アクションのえいががすきです。

   >>*Is my translation here accurate? Does this sentence make sense?*
7. We love to **drink** and **smoke.**

   わたしたちはおさけ**をのみます**とたばこ**をすいます**がだいすきです。

   >>*Is it necessary to have をのみます and をすいます here?*
8. **Often, we do it all over again on saturday too.**

   **よこ、どようびはもいちどします。**

   >>*This is probably all wrong, yea?*
9. This summer I will go on a phillipines trip with him.

   はちがつからのやすみにオーストラリアりょこう**する**。

   >>*Do I need to end with a です for this sentence?*

Phew. I hope my formatting makes it a little more bearable!

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to JLU!  It appears that you're asking nine unrelated questions.  On this site, it's best if you ask *one question at a time*.  Could you please edit your post and remove the eight of the questions?  (You can post additional questions separately later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `そして` is fine here, but I would say そしてことし**は**25さいです to emphasize **this** year.
2. Just `かぞく`; use `ごかぞく` when you're speaking *to* him about his family

> ごかぞくはおげんきですか？
>
> You're fine with just `いっしょに` **IF** you've already established `私たち` is a previous sentence/context.  Otherwise put both.  The second part should be something like `メニューのやすいレストラン`.
>
> Correct
>
> Correct
>
> Translation is OK, but I'd say something like "Since our lives aren't very interesting..."  In this context, I suppose "lacks action" is OK, but that's not a direct translation.  The Japanese sentence is fine though.
>
> This is incorrect.  To nominalize a verb, you need the dictionary form + `の／こと`.  So the sentence should be `私たちはおさけをのむこととたばこをすうことことがだいすきです。`
>
> `よく`, not `よこ`; `もういちど`, not `もいちど`
>
> No, do not end this with `です`, plus it should be `オーストラリアへのりょこうにいきます` or more simply `オーストラリアにいきます`.  For with him, you forgot to add `かれと`.  Also, the katakana says "Australia" even though you wrote "Phillipines".
>
> I realize you're probably a beginning, but man it's hard to read and write only in kana!